# Live Linux which does not mount any hard drive in the computer

Tags: linux, access-control, physical, usb-drive

I am searching for a Linux System which runs from a CD and does not mount any hard drive of the computer.

**I want to prevent any possiblity to write something on the hard drive of the computer** and on the current operating system which is installed on any harddrive in the computer.

Comment: This is pretty similar to: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/a-computing-environment-that-saves-no-data/

Comment: Also you can just unplug the harddisks while you boot up your live cd. Otherwise [CAINE](http://www.caine-live.net/) is your best bet.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as CAINE is based on Ubuntu, based on Debian, my remark concerning automatic use of swap partition may be right too!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backtrack 5 gives you the option when booting to start in forensic mode which means it will not attempt to mount any drives, unless specifically requested by the user.

Comment: Have you experiences with CAINE? http://www.caine-live.net/ this seems also to be interesting

Answer (score 2):

Look for anything that has a Forensic mode.  Forensic mode is not allowed to make any changes to existing hardware state and should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The basic GNU/Debian Live does the job, but don't **prevent** from **requested** access to connected hardware.

Many Debian based live system, like Ubuntu or Backtrack do this in same way:

- Run live system using only ram, cpu and networks connections.
- Give the ability to mount accessible partitions... or not.
- Give the ability to scan present hardware in *read-only* mode for making discrete copy of whole hard drive, for sample.

Because I'm Debian user and prefer Debian stability than Ubuntu's modernity, I use Debian live. With the *`Debian Live Helper`*, who let me create my own Debian Live, with all *forensic* tools as a simple build option... Upto date, effectively. (If I run LiveHelper now, all packages are from today's debian repositories).

**Nota** If there is one useable linux swap partition present on hardrive and system don't have lot memory (less than 512Mo), some versions of Live systems may try to use them even without user confirmation! This could break an *hibernation* state!!

If current installed OS is not Linux, you could be quiet.